# How to map a C array to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, marshalling

My question has to do with trying to call a function written in C from C#. I've looked in a header file that came with the C library to understand the functions as they exist in the C dll. Here's what I see:

C code (for a function called "LocGetLocations"):

```
typedef enum {
    eLocNoError,
    eLocInvalidCriteria,
    eLocNoMatch, 
    eLocNoMoreLocations,
    eLocConnectionError, 
    eLocContextError,
    eLocMemoryError
} tLocGetStatus; 

typedef void *tLocFindCtx;

typedef void *tLocation;    

PREFIX unsigned int POSTFIX LocGetLocations
(
    tLocFindCtx pCtx, 
    tLocation *pLoc,
    unsigned int pNumLocations,
    tLocGetStatus *pStatus
);
```

In C#, I have this:

```
[DllImport(@"VertexNative\Location.dll")]
public static extern uint LocGetLocations(IntPtr findContext, out byte[] locations, uint numberLocations, out int status);
```

The problem is that I don't quite know how to handle the pLoc parameter in C#. I'm bringing it over as a byte array, although I'm not sure if that is correct. The C library's documentation says that that parameter is a pointer to an array of handles.

How can I get an array back on the C# side and access its data?

The example I was given in C, looks like this:

```
tLocation lLocation[20];

// other stuff

LocGetLocations(lCtx, lLocation, 20, &lStatus)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If it's an array of handles, you'll want to make it an array of `IntPtr`.

Comment: See http://pinvoke.net/index.aspx for lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, this signature works:

```
[DllImport(@"VertexNative\Location.dll")]
public static extern uint LocGetLocations(IntPtr findContext, [Out] IntPtr[] locations, uint numberLocations, out int status);
```

And I can call it like this (some refactoring needed):

```
IntPtr[] locations = new IntPtr[20];
int status;
// findContext is gotten from another method invocation
uint result = GeoCodesNative.LocGetLocations(findContext, locations, 20, out status);
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note, I think that it was my use of the "out" keyword that was tripping me up. Removing it got me farther. This makes sense, I guess, since arrays are reference types to begin with and don't need to be outed to assign a local variable to the new value from the method.

Comment: @Nick: What you want is to add the [OutAttribute] (or just [Out]) to IntPtr[] locations. This tells the marshaller to only copy on the way out, not both in and out. This saves one unecessary block copy from happening.

Comment: Adding out to IntPtr[] locations gives me a runtime error though.

Comment: I edited your answer to show what I mean. Not `out`, `[Out]`.

Comment: `out` is a parameter modifier. `[Out]` is an attribute, specifically `System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute`. This attribute is examined, not by the compiler, but at runtime by the CLR marshaller. To marshall means to allocate unmanaged memory, copy from managed memory to unmanaged, call the unmanaged function, then copy from unmanaged back to managed. The `[In]` and `[Out]` attributes allow you to control which copying occurs as both are on by default.

Comment: Very nice. Adding [Out] makes the C method return values that otherwise came back empty. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the only thing that matters is the size of the parameters. As I recall enums are integers in C, so you can simply use that. Or better, recreate the same enum in C#, I think it would work. One thing to remember is that when dealing with complex structs, one needs to use attributes to tell the framework about the desired alignment of members.